# table positioning with AJAX to PHP post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jQuery script that sends POST data via AJAX to a php file that then creates a table. I have used firebug to check the console and everything gets created properly. On the `success:` I reload the window and the table isn't displayed.

I know the table html was created properly from the php file because I commented out the `reload` so I could see exactly what it created) I have lots of things displayed on my page and would like the table in a particular spot. How can I get the table to actually display where I want it to?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stayinfobutton").click(function () {
        var id = $('#id').val();
        var dataString = {
            id: id
        };
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "classes/table_auto_guests.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            /*success: function(html)
                    {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    }*/
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: save that value in the database and get it after the page reloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `window.location` call will reload a new page in the browser window, this will loose the data returned to the ajax call by the server.

Usually the response to Ajax calls is loaded directly into your page, something like:

```
success: function(html)
{
   $('#guestsTable').html(html);
   $('userForm').hide();
}
```

I made up the guestsTable div and userForm names, ;).

The return data may need some coercing to make it into html (I'm assuming your using JQuery), hopefully the php script will set it to `html/text` in the header, also `dataType: html` can be passed in the `$.ajax({...})` call.

Alternatively, if the `classes/table_auto_guests.php` returns a full page which you want to load in the browser, Ajax may not be what you are looking for. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit) contains code on how to submit the data as a form, and load the result as a new page.